# Split and randomly reassemble a time series, but maintain leap years in R

Tags: r

I need to create datasets of weather data to use for modeling over the next 50 years.  I am planning to do this by using historical weather data (daily, 1980-2012), but mixing up the years in a random order and then relabeling them with 2014-2054.  However, I cannot be completely random, because it is important to maintain leap years.  I want to have as many datasets as possible so I can get an average response of the model to different weather patterns.

Here is an example of what the historical data looks like (except there is data for every day).  How could I reassemble it so the years are in a different order, but make sure years with 366 days (1980, 1984, 1988) end up in future leap years (2016, 2020, 2024, 2028, 2052)?  And then do that at least 50 more times?

```
year          day           radn          maxt      
 1980          1             5.827989     -1.59375      
 1980          2             5.655813     -1.828125     
 1980          3             6.159346     -0.96875   
 1981          4             6.065136     -1.84375    
 1981          5             5.961181     -2.34375     
 1981          6             5.758733     -2.0625       
 1981          7             6.458055     -2.90625     
 1982          8             6.73056      -2.890625   
 1982          9             6.89472      -1.796875    
 1983          10            6.687879     -2.140625     
 1984          11            6.585833     -1.609375     
 1984          12            6.466392     -0.71875      
 1984          13            7.100092     -0.515625      
 1985          14            7.176402     -1.734375    
 1985          15            7.236122     -2.5         
 1985          16            7.455515     -2.375       
 1986          17            7.395174     -1.390625    
 1986          18            7.341537     -2.21875    
 1987          19            7.678102     -2.828125   
 1987          20            7.539239     -2.875        
 1987          21            7.231031     -2.390625    
 1988          22            7.397067     -0.21875     
 1988          23            7.947912     -0.5         
 1989          24            8.355059     -1.03125      
 1990          25            8.145792     -1.5         
 1990          26            8.591616     -2.078125
```

Comment: Given that 2000 was a leap year, you can get away with adding multiples of 4.

Comment: 1980-2012 is 33 years, but 2014-2054 is 41 years. Are you sampling with replacement?

Comment: Yes, @josilber, sampling with replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that scrambles the years of a passed data frame df, returning a new data frame:

```
scramble.years = function(df) {
  # Build convenience vectors of years
  early.leap = seq(1980, 2012, 4)
  late.leap = seq(2016, 2052, 4)
  early.nonleap = seq(1980, 2012)[!seq(1980, 2012) %in% early.leap]
  late.nonleap = seq(2014, 2054)[!seq(2014, 2054) %in% late.leap]

  # Build map from late years to early years
  map = data.frame(from=c(sample(early.leap, length(late.leap), replace=T),
                          sample(early.nonleap, length(late.nonleap), replace=T)),
                   to=c(late.leap, late.nonleap))

  # Build a new data frame with the correct years/days for later period
  return.list = lapply(2014:2054, function(x) {
     get.df = subset(df, year == map$from[map$to == x])
     get.df$year = x
     return(get.df)
  })
  return(do.call(rbind, return.list))
}
```

You can call `scramble.years` any number of times to get new scrambled data frames.

Comment: I started using this function again because I need to expand the dataset and I'm getting some problems depending on how the data lines up.  I get the error `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "year", value = 2028L) :  replacement has 1 row, data has 0` the value always = leap year.  It didn't matter too much when I was doing small sets, but now it's really slowing me down for the larger one.  Any idea for the fix, @josilber?